# How does Ruby's Object#const_get actually work?

Tags: ruby

I have recently discovered that Ruby (2.2.1) has some "interesting" behavior.

```
module Foo
  class Foo
  end
  class Bar
  end
end

Foo.const_get('Foo') #=> Foo::Foo
Foo.const_get('Bar') #=> Foo::Bar
Foo.const_get('Foo::Foo') #=> Foo
Foo.const_get('Foo::Bar') #=> NameError: uninitialized constant Foo::Foo::Bar
Foo.const_get('Foo::Foo::Bar') #=> Foo::Bar
Foo.const_get('Foo::Foo::Foo::Bar') #=> NameError: uninitialized constant Foo::Foo::Bar
Foo.const_get('Foo::Foo::Foo::Foo::Bar') #=> Foo::Bar
Foo.const_get('Foo::Foo::Foo') #=> Foo::Foo
Foo.const_get('Foo::Foo::Foo::Foo') #=> Foo
Foo.const_get('Foo::Foo::Foo::Foo::Foo') #=> Foo::Foo
Foo.const_get('Foo::Foo::Foo::Foo::Foo::Foo') #=> Foo
```

This is a bit surprising.  My understanding has been that `const_get` first looks for a constant in the receiver's collection of constants and then looks at Object's constants.  OK, fine. Why then does the fourth `Foo#const_get` above fail and the third one doesn't?

I'm also curious as to why calling `Foo#const_get` alternates between the module and class depending on how many `::Foo`s you add.

Comment: Can you check your third example (`Foo.const_get('Foo::Foo')`)? I get just `Foo`, not `Foo::Foo`.

Comment: @matt You are correct, it does just return `Foo`.  Edited original question.

Comment: @Huliax Is there a way to get the object instance if both the module and the nested module name is same, just like Foo:Foo

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[The docs say](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Module.html#method-i-const_get):

> This method will recursively look up constant names if a namespaced class name is provided.

So `Foo.const_get('Foo::Bar')` is basically the same as `Foo.const_get('Foo').const_get('Bar')`. Using this interpretation your results make sense.

Your third example:

```
Foo.const_get('Foo::Foo')
```

is the same as

```
Foo.const_get('Foo').const_get('Foo')
```

The first `const_get` looks at constants defined within the top level `Foo` (the module), and finds the nested class. So the whole thing effectively becomes:

```
Foo::Foo.const_get('Foo')
```

The second call then looks at the class, first looking the any contained constants (finding none) and then looking in its ancestors. `Object` is an ancestor, and has the top level `Foo` module as a constant, so this is found and returned.

This also explains the alternation when adding extra `::Foo`s. The alternation is between `const_get` on the top level module finding the nested class, and on the nested class looking up the inheritance chain and finding the top level module.

The fourth example, `Foo.const_get('Foo::Bar')`, which raises an exception, can also be explained. It is equivalent to

```
Foo.const_get('Foo').const_get('Bar')
```

The first part, `Foo.const_get('Foo')` is the same as the case above, evaluating to `Foo::Foo`, so the whole thing now effectively becomes:

```
Foo::Foo.const_get('Bar')
```

Now the nested `Foo` class doesn’t contain a `Bar` constant, and looking up the inheritance chain, neither does `Object`, so the result is a `NameError`.